# How to fix my postgres function syntax to fit a user parameter

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause, greatest-n-per-group, sql-function

I'm trying to make a postgreql function, I'm a little confused on which syntax format to use when I'm passing a select statement that takes in a parameter (this parameter can be a string or a list of strings)

Here is the original select query that I used before, with `placeholders` as my parameter. This select works great for me!

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (symbol) symbol,
                next_dividend_date, ex_dividend_date
           FROM api.security_stats 
           WHERE api.security_stats.symbol 
           IN ({placeholders}) 
           ORDER BY symbol, date desc;
```

The problem is when I tried and transform the above into a usable function, where users can enter the parameter for the function. I can't get the syntax to work however. Also, there are a lot of syntax examples in the psql [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-createfunction.html) for functions. I'm not sure which one to use for my case?

```
CREATE FUNCTION dividend(stocks char)
RETURNS TABLE(symbol char, next_dividend_date date, ex_dividend_date date) AS $$
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (symbol) symbol, next_dividend_date, ex_dividend_date
                                                FROM api.security_stats 
                                                WHERE api.security_stats.symbol 
                                                IN ({stocks}) ORDER BY symbol, date desc) 
                                                $$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

I'm trying to allow for the parameter, `stocks`, to be inputted by the user client.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like:

```
create function dividend(p_stocks char)
    returns table(symbol char, next_dividend_date date, ex_dividend_date date) 
as $$
    select distinct on (symbol) symbol, next_dividend_date, ex_dividend_date
    from api.security_stats 
    where api.security_stats.symbol = any(string_to_array($1, ','))
    order by symbol, date desc 
$$ language sql;
```

That's table-returning SQL function; you can refer to the input argument with positional notation `$1`.

Between the lines of your question, I understand that the argument is a comma-separated string, so I added an extra step to parse it to an array, that can then be searched using operator `any`.

Or, if you want to pass your input as an array:

```
create function dividend(p_stocks text[])
    returns table(symbol char, next_dividend_date date, ex_dividend_date date) 
as $$
    select distinct on (symbol) symbol, next_dividend_date, ex_dividend_date
    from api.security_stats 
    where api.security_stats.symbol = any($1)
    order by symbol, date desc 
$$ language sql;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying everything. Looking at this snippet, now I understand the function parameters for postgres. I haven't yet tested it but will comment back in a short while and let you know!

Comment: I'm able to get this query working! thank you so much, I do however have a question, does this method only allow for one string in the parameter? What if I have a list of strings. For example, `select dividend('MSFT');` this works great! But when I try to do, `select dividend('MSFT', 'AAPL');` The function doesn't seem to work, am I meant to structure the input differently?

Comment: @Dre: the function accepts a CSV string, so that would be: `select dividend('MSFT,AAPL')`. Or you could change the function code to accept directly an array, and call it like: `select divident(array['MSFT', 'AAPL'])`

Comment: For curiosity sake, how would the other function look like that directly accepts an array? I'm thinking which would be a better option for my particular use case. If I'm using this query as part of a web app, I think the array format might be better? Less data transformation.

Comment: you've set me up very well for my next functions, thank you so much for the help!